# Angular ngResource post with API key

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, codeigniter-3

I am using the Code Igniter REST library to serve my api. I am trying to protect my api to keyed access. I can successfully retrieve info in my application using ngResource and the key however I am getting a 403 refusal when trying to post with the same key. For now I am simply embedding the key in my factories.

Here is my successful factory:

```
.factory('Breweries', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    var key = '621d004e78de5b1ef9c634ae3fc9b84a';
    return $resource('http://restapi.dev/api/breweries?key=' + key, {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
    });
}
])
```

And the unsuccessful factory:

```
.factory('Claim', function($resource) {
var key = '621d004e78de5b1ef9c634ae3fc9b84a';
var Claim = $resource('http://restapi.dev/api/system/:method?key=' + key, {}, {
    save: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            method: 'claim'
        }
    },
    send: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            method: 'contact'
        }
    }
});

return Claim;
})
```

Both factories work and function properly without the key so I am not far off. I appreciate any help. I believe I am using resource a little improperly for this however I have only found references to submitting the key as a header and not a query.

Answer (score 0):

An interceptor is simply a regular service factory that is registered to that array. Using AngularJS interceptors with $http

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors